# OAuth2 Multiple sessions (devices) on same client id

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0

For our mobile app we're running an API which uses OAuth2 for user and client authentication. We're using a stripped down version of OAuth which does not use scopes or client grants since the only apps that will be using the API are written by us. Each app (Android and iOS for now, but planning on web app and more mobile) has an own Client ID and a Client Secret and until recently we allowed each client to only have one session per user. This however raises a problem when a user has an Android phone and Android tablet. The way our API works now is that when the user is logged in on his phone and then tries to sign in on their tablet, the phone session will be deleted. We could simply remove the constraint of one session per Client, but we also do not want multiple sessions per device (2 sessions on the same phone)

My question is, how can we allow multiple sessions (devices) per Client while still being able to identify the individual devices? (I still want only one session per device).

We're considering generating a unique hash on the client upon client authentication which is shared to the API and stored on both the client and the API. There must however have already been people with this particular problem and I'm curious to their solutions (and I obviously haven't found any satisfying answers searching online).

Many thanks.

Some implementation specifics:

- NodeJS API
- Passport & oauth2orize OAuth implementation
- ResourceOwnerPasswordStrategy (for authenticating a client and user in one) & ClientPasswordStrategy (we also support FB login so we still need to authorize the client when doing that)
- Bearer tokens

Comment: I know this was quite some time ago but was wondering what implementation you ended up going with or if you found the answer you were looking for? I happen to be running into the same use case and can't seem to enter the right combination of words into google to preset the answer I desire. Any insight could help

Comment: No Worries, I ended up NOT making the sessionId + clientId combination unique. In other words, I am allowing multiple sessions per client, which in theory allows multiple sessions per device. This works most of the time as a client with a session can be identified with the sessionId. If for some reason the client loses that sessionId (app uninstall, db reset etc..) the client has to create a new session anyway. You'll end up with some idle sessions which will never be used, but if you look at the Google or dropbox session dashboard you'll still see your old sessions from old devices as well.

Comment: Yea, it sounds like I have been coming to that same conclusion. Specific to the flow of passport/oauth, where in the flow did you have the client send their generated session token to the server? Did you end up injecting middleware in front of the oauth2orize middleware which would capture the session token sent by the client or something better? Or does applying a final middleware function after oauth2orize middleware still allow you to access the request body unaltered?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your question. I have the client send their session token in the Authorization header to the server. I use passport/oauth2orize which then verifies the session and client. After that passport will deserialize your user (`passport.deserializeUser`) after which the user will be available as `req.user` for the rest of the flow. As for the request body, I believe its not available yet in the middleware, though I don't use it at that stage. I really solely on the auth token to verify a request. Any other logic is in the route handler itself.

Comment: Oh, what I do use in the verification process is fetching the user in the passport/oauth2orize middleware (you need it anyway in order to verify the request). I store the userId with the session so thats how I'm able to fetch the user belonging to the session.

Comment: My apologies for bugging you continuously but I think I am close to what I need. I figured out the session stuff with ExpressJS and passport/oauth2orize, but what I am trying to ultimately achieve is having access tokens assigned to the session rather than the user account so that "devices" can share the same account without invalidating each other potentially. I can't seem to find an instance during the client-password exchange where i would be able to link the sessionid with the access/refresh tokens. I feel like I might be missing something? lol

Comment: No worries. The trick is to store the session (which is in essence the token) separately from the user and allow a user to have multiple sessions (so no unique combi on userId - sessionId ). You use the token to find the session and get the appropriate user with the userId stored within that session. This way session has a many to one relationship to a user object. So a session stores its token, the userId, expiry logic and other metadata you might need. The user itself is stored separately.